# What is the most Pythonic way to loop over a list where certain entries act as headers for subsequent entries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-parsing

As the result of logging a CLI tool command's system output...

```py
import subprocess
list_operations_cmd = 'cloud_cli_tool --list'
all_operations_sysout = subprocess.check_output(list_operations_cmd, shell=True)
```

I get a string that looks like this:

```sh
Project: foo foo foo (Environment: PRODUCTION)
  ipsum dolor sit
  Excepteur sint occaecat
  POST aliquip ex ea
Project: foo foo foo (Environment: DEVELOPMENT)
  ipsum dolor sit
  Excepteur sint occaecat
  POST aliquip ex ea
Project: bar (Environment: PRODUCTION)
  velit esse cillum
  occaecat cupidatat
```

I want to turn it into a data structure that looks like this to faciliate my work doing input sanitization against parameters of a command interface that I'm writing this Python script to expose to system users.

```py
[
 {
  project: "foo foo foo",
  environment: "PRODUCTION",
  operation: "ipsum dolor sit"
 },
 {
  project: "foo foo foo",
  environment: "PRODUCTION",
  operation: "Excepteur sint occaecat"
 },
 {
  project: "foo foo foo",
  environment: "PRODUCTION",
  operation: "POST aliquip ex ea"
 },
 {
  project: "foo foo foo",
  environment: "DEVELOPMENT",
  operation: "ipsum dolor sit"
 },
 {
  project: "foo foo foo",
  environment: "DEVELOPMENT",
  operation: "Excepteur sint occaecat"
 },
 {
  project: "foo foo foo",
  environment: "DEVELOPMENT",
  operation: "POST aliquip ex ea"
 },
 {
  project: "bar",
  environment: "PRODUCTION)",
  operation: "velit esse cillum"
 },
 {
  project: "bar",
  environment: "PRODUCTION)",
  operation: "occaecat cupidatat"
 }
]
```

As you can see, a change of project/environment can be detected by a newline w/ no indentation; a change of record can be detected by a newline followed by two spaces.  The project/environment lines act as "headers" for the following lines until a new "project/environment line" is detected.

I know I could just `.splitlines()` the whole thing & start looping one line at a time, caching things & if-then-elsing them ... but it felt like maybe there was a more Pythonic way to do it than:

```py
proj_env_pattern = r'^Project: (.*) \(Environment: (.*)\)$'
all_operations_list = all_operations_sysout.splitlines()
for line in all_operations_list[:20]:
    is_header = False
    if not line.startswith('  '):
        is_header = True
        project = re.search(proj_env_pattern, line, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
        print project
        # TO DO:  code...
    # TO:  code...
```

Python 2.7.5 on Linux; can't install any new modules.

---

**Update:**

Thanks @fsimonjetz for the tip.  If you want to make it an answer, I can accept & close.

Code is now much tidier than I would have done it:

```py
import re
import subprocess

def get_all_operations():
    list_operations_cmd = 'cloud_cli_tool --list'
    proj_env_pattern = r'^(.*) \(Environment: (.*)\)$'
    all_operations_list = []
    all_projects = subprocess.check_output(list_operations_cmd, shell=True).split('Project: ')
    for project in all_projects[1:]:
        project_lines = project.splitlines()
        project_search = re.search(proj_env_pattern, project_lines[0])
        for line in project_lines[1:]:
            all_operations_list.append({'project': project_search.group(1), 'environment': project_search.group(2), 'operation': line.lstrip()})
    return all_operations_list

print get_all_operations()
```

Comment: What have you tried until now? What's not working? @k..

Comment: Well, I know I could `.splitlines()` and loop over it one at a time and do all sorts of manual if-else things looking for the changes from one line to the next, but I'm not very good at the "more clever" ways to do things and was just curious if anyone had any "cleverer," "more Pythonic" ideas.  Updated question.

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Then write some. Stop worrying about how Pythonic your code is until you have something that works.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep editing the question as I write.  Shrug.  Of course, then I would have working code, and I could move on with my job anyway ... I just thought I could find friendly people here who might teach me a Python trick I didn't know.

Comment: If the input is that regular, you don't even need regular expressions. Could just `.split('Project:')` the whole string first to get all the fragments into a list, then loop over it to extract the other parts.

Comment: @fsimonjetz -- clever -- thank you, that's the kind of trick I knew someone else would be able to suggest!!!  Want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @fsimonjetz for the tip.  If you want to make it an answer, I can accept, but adding what I implemented at your suggestion in the comments so that this no longer looks unanswered to people skimming for things to answer.

Solution is leveraging the lucky fact that all "header lines" start with `Project:`  and breaking the overall sysout string into per-header substrings with `.split('Project: ')`.  For each substring, further parsing is the usual regex, `.splitlines()`, & `[1:]` list slicing.

```py
import re
import subprocess

def get_all_operations():
    list_operations_cmd = 'cloud_cli_tool --list'
    proj_env_pattern = r'^(.*) \(Environment: (.*)\)$'
    all_operations_list = []
    all_projects = subprocess.check_output(list_operations_cmd, shell=True).split('Project: ')
    for project in all_projects[1:]:
        project_lines = project.splitlines()
        project_search = re.search(proj_env_pattern, project_lines[0])
        for line in project_lines[1:]:
            all_operations_list.append({'project': project_search.group(1), 'environment': project_search.group(2), 'operation': line.lstrip()})
    return all_operations_list

print get_all_operations()
```